# foreign-key on a table not in the database, with ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, propel

I have a static table `entry` that's shared by several databases/website. By static, I mean the data is read but never updated by the websites. Currently, all websites are served from the same server but that may change.

I want to minimize the need for creating/maintaining this table for each of the websites, so I thought about turning it to a variable that's stored in a shared library that all websites have access to.

**The problem is I use an ORM and use foreign key constraints to ensure referential integrity of the ids used from that static table,** so by removing that table out of the MySQL database into a variable, how can I still get referential integrity for the ids referenced from that table? Do I have to do it entirely programmatically or is there a trick to still treat the data as if coming from a real db table.

My database definition (using Propel) originally looked like this, where the `refer` table had a field `linkto` that was referencing the `id` of the `entry` table. Now that the `entry` table is in code, I can't do the foreign-key trick any more, or can I somehow get the same effect?

```
  <table name="entry">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="title" type="VARCHAR" size="500" required="true" />
  </table>

  <table name="refer">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="linkto" type="INTEGER"/>
     <foreign-key foreignTable="entry">
        <reference local="linkto" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
```

**And of course are these any other efficient ways to do the same thing? I just don't want to have to repeat that table for several websites.**

Answer (score 1):

You could create a constraint -- a mighty verbose one, probably, if your `id` FK is being replaced by a link -- but then you'd still be in the position of maintaining this constraint for each web site.  It would help to know what these tables are actually tracking/being used for if you want suggestions for other ways of handling it.

Comment: looks like SO was not displaying my table definition even though I had in the post. I've highlighted it as code so now it's showing. Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: @sami - it would still help to know what it is used for.